# Register user in ejabberd with xmpphp

Tags: php

I have connected ejabberd xmpp server with xmpphp library. Its working fine. I need to create a user in ejabberd xmpp server using xmpphp library.
So i have added following two functions in XMPPHP/XMPP.php file :

```
public function register($username, $password = null){

 if (!isset($password)) $password = $this->genRandomString(15);
 $id = 'reg_' . $this->getID();
 $xml = "<iq type='set' id='$id'>
 <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
 <username>" . $username . "</username>
 <password>" . $password . "</password>
 <email></email>
 <name></name>
 </query>
 </iq>";
 $this->addIdHandler($id, 'register_new_user_handler');
 $this->send($xml);
  }



 protected function register_new_user_handler($xml){
  switch ($xml->attrs['type']) {
  case 'error':
  $this->event('new_user_registered', 'error');
  break;
  case 'result':
  $query = $xml->sub('query');
  $username='';
  $password='';
  if(!is_array($query->subs)) {
  foreach ($query->sub as $key => $value) {
  switch ($value->name) {
  case 'username':
  $username = $value->data;
  break;
  case 'password':
  $password = $value->data;
  break;
  }
  }
  }
  $this->event('new_user_registered', array('jid' => $username . "@{$this->server}", 'password' => $password));
  default:
  $this->event('new_user_registered', 'default');
  }
 }
```

and m calling the above functions in sendmessage_example.php as follows :

```
<?php

// activate full error reporting
//error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT);

include 'XMPPHP/XMPP.php';


$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('serverhost', 5222, 'admin@localhost', 'password', 'xmpphp', 'localhost', $printlog=false, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);

try {
    $conn->connect();
    $conn->processUntil('session_start');
    $conn->presence();
 $conn->register('uname', 'pass');


    $conn->message('vaiju@localhost', 'This is a test message!');
    $conn->disconnect();
} catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

I have manually added a user called vaiju. I'm able to connect it and m getting a message in my pidgin client. But user registration is not working properly.

Comment: What's the response to your iq request from the jabber server?

Comment: i'm not getting any response but getiing a message as This is a test message. but user is not creating on ejabberd server.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this. tested and working with me.

```
define('JABBER_REST_HOST','localhost:5285');
define('JABBER_REST_URL','http://localhost:5285/rest');

$request        = "register ketan13 localhost ketan13";
$jabberResponse =  sendRESTRequest(JABBER_REST_URL, $request);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($jabberResponse);

function sendRESTRequest ($url, $request) {
    // Create a stream context so that we can POST the REST request to $url
    $context = stream_context_create (array ('http' => array ('method' => 'POST'
                                            ,'header' => "Host: ".JABBER_REST_HOST."\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nContent-Length: ".strlen($request)
                                            ,'content' => $request)));
    // Use file_get_contents for PHP 5+ otherwise use fopen, fread, fclose
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '>=')) {
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    } else {
        // This is the PHP4 workaround which is slightly less elegant
        // Suppress fopen warnings, otherwise they interfere with the page headers
        $fp = @fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
        $result = '';
        // Only proceed if we have a file handle, otherwise we enter an infinite loop
        if ($fp) {
            while(!feof($fp)) {
                $result .= fread($fp, 4096);
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: No, its not working for me. Can u just explain the above code? so that i can make it work.

Comment: have you changed URL accordingly? and does port 5285 is open ? also send error code if it's not working.

Comment: Still it is not working. I am not getting any errorcode.

Comment: check whether you added proper plugins on server.